# Regular expression with domain in src

Tags: regex, wordpress, search, expression

I am using wordpress with Search Regex plugin. My problem is the following. I have nearly one thousand articles with two iframes. I want to use search regex to delete the iframe containing a certain domain in src. I used the following regex code for searching it :

```
#(<iframe.*youtube.com.*>)(</iframe>)#
```

The search gives me the first iframe alongside the second. Is there a delimiter or a better expression to search just for the iframe containing youtube in search regex?

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454